# Автозаполнение формы и валидатор реактивных форм

Tags: angular2, angular4

Я создал реактивную форму на angular2+, и после заполнения данные сохранились в браузер, но если обновить страницу с формой данные подобьются а валидность формы не измениться пока не клацнуть по форме мышкой. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.validateAllFormFields(this.form);
}



  validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
      const control = formGroup.get(field);
      if (control instanceof FormControl) {
        control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
      } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
        this.validateAllFormFields(control);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: window.onload = () => {
            this.validateAllFormFields(this.form);
}; не работает

Comment: Вам надо вызвать этот метод в ngAfterContentInit() {}

Comment: не получиться, эта проблема в браузере хром. Я привязывал двухсторонней привязкой поля, поле логин автозаполняется нормально, а вот пароль undefined пока не кликнишь где нибудь. Это проблема браузера

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с changeDetection